# Is it possible to model calories burned using mass of the human, avg velocity and time travelled

Tags: kinematics, everyday-life, models

I know it's impossible to get the *exact* value of calorie burned but a heuristic or an approximation would be just enough.

Given human body is 70% efficient then calorie burned=3.33*energy dissipated

Comment: If the answer is yes, I'm definitely going to stop using my treadmill on an incline.

Comment: The human body is FAR below 70% thermodynamic efficiency.